# File opened but could not read

Tags: perl

```
my $myFile = "akshay.txt";  
open my $IO, "<", $myFile or    die ("Cant open $myFile because $!");
print "File $myFile has opened successfully\n";
my $line = <$myFile>;
print $line;
close $IO;
```

Error:

```
File akshay.txt has **opened successfully**
readline() on **unopened filehandle** at akshay.pl line 29.
Use of uninitialized value $line in print at akshay.pl line 30.
```

Why is this contradiction ?
Running on Windows and ActivePerl.

Comment: You are trying to read data from file name, not from file itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the file handle to read it:

```
my $line = <$IO>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
my $line = <$myFile>;
```

to

```
my $line = <$IO>;
```

You are using filename variable to read the file content. Use the filehandle.

Answer (score 0):

You have use the filename variable instead of the filehandle variable, fixed code should look like this:

```
my $myFile = "akshay.txt";
open my $IO, "<", $myFile or die("Cant open $myFile because $!");
print "File $myFile has opened successfully\n";
my $line = <$IO>;
print $line;
close $IO;
```